# The document project.xcworkspace could not be opened

Tags: xcode, xcode-project

I am having trouble opening basically all my .xcodeproj on my mac. However, when I clicked on show contents of my xcode proj I can see the xcworkspace file but I can't open it. I wonder if anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

okay I can't post img yet but the error was on title:
The document project.xcworkspace could not be opened

Comment: did you upgrade to MacOS Catalina since you can't open the files?

Answer (score 5):

1. Delete XCWorkspace and podfile.lock from project folder
2. Then go to project folder from terminal, and just type command pod install

Answer (score 4):

I have this problem as well. This is not an error from Xcode itself, it is related to the last macOS catalina update. Each time I get this error the Preview App suddenly presents the same problem with some PDF files.

The temporal solution is just restart your mac and work on your projects until the error comes back again....

Comment: same problem here with Xcode [Version 11.2.1 (11B500)] on Catalina (X 15.1); needed to restart the Mac

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, but i did not received any error message, my x-code 11.3 quit while opening the xcworkspace.

I was able to solve it by: 
- Open the xcworkspace project with xcode 10.3, indexed the project automatically by xcode.
- After that I was able to open it in xcode 11.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `git`, and you have done a `merge` or `pull` recently, check for posible **conflicts** on your `.xcworkspace` file.

In order to do that open your folder, and right click on your `.xcworkspace` and select `show package content`

[image]

Once you clicked open with `textEdit` the `contents.xcworkspacedata`, and check for conflicts.

[image]

In my case a conflict was happening at this file. So in order to solved the problem you just have solved the conflict.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
      location = "example1.gpx">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "example.gpx">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
>>>>>>> 62cf54792d2bfa804a7cf31505805e8983e14361
      location = "example.gpx">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

**Solved conflict:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "example.gpx">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

Once you have solved the conflict your proyect should open correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar problem here, Catalina, Xcode 11.2.1
However: this project *does not have an xcworkspace*, just an xcodeproj. And still it gives the same error: weird.

Comment: .xcodeprojs have a “default” workspace named project.xcworkspace inside them. That’s what this error is referring to.

Comment: Yeah, Apple's naming scheme is a bit ... convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open xcworkspace file in higher version Xcode whichever in your system.
2. Once opened , Quit Xcode Project
3. Quit Xcode
4. Open your Project in your require Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

i had the similar issue, how i fixed is i moved my project to desktop from other file then it worked, it was saved in autosave information, hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R $USER /Users/admin/rd/source-codes/mobile

The main issue is your user permission

1. Make sure don's use sudo to install npm and pod
2. npm and pod, use normal user which is you
3. when you install npm and pod, I might encounter permission issue also
4. no worries, just look for the parent folder and change the user permission using below command

sudo chown -R $USER /Users/admin/rd/source-codes/mobile

I spent a few days, and finally I used this command and solved it out for me.